# PHP Codeigniter - Apache virtual host setup trouble

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, vhosts

This has been doing my head in. Hope you guys can help. I can't find out where the error lies.

*httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot /home/tilman/Sites/mysite/www
    ServerName mysite.lo
</VirtualHost>
```

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   mysite.lo
```

*config.php*

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://mysite.lo";
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

*www/.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Now `http://mysite.lo` shows me the default controller. `http://mysite.lo/index.php` as well. So does `http://mysite.lo/index.php/welcome`.

But `http://mysite.lo/welcome` doesn't.

`http://localhost/mysite/www/welcome` works as expected.

---

edit:
I want to move system and application out of the web root.
So my file structure looks like this:

```
application/
system/
www/
 '- index.php
```

In index.php I changed the paths to system and application folder, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you're having rewritemod/htaccess issues rather than VirtualHost issues. Have you made sure that you've got a block such as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.lo
  <Directory /home/tilman/Sites/mysite>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

somewhere within your config files? The fact that /index.php and /index.php/welcome work, tell me that it's the rewrite mod that's not functioning...

Comment: Man, so silly, I simply forgot to add that directive. Good eye. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up here with a problem related to loading static assets (css, js...) for a CakePHP site on index.php and also with a CodeIgniter site that was loading the index.php perfectly but then all the internal routing was giving 404 errors. I added the "AllowOverride All" for the directory configuration and that did the trick for both issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your virtual host, do you not need this?

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot /home/tilman/Sites/mysite
    ServerName mysite.lo
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure you needed the `www` portion.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry about not mentioning in the first place.